# android action bar doesnt appear

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am not sure why the action bar does not appear on my main menu, i already cleaned my project but it still doesn't work.

**the main xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
<item android:id="@+id/mainmenu" 
    android:title="Main Menu"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
<item android:id="@+id/play_actionbar" 
    android:title="Play"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
<item android:id="@+id/admin_actionbar" 
    android:title="Admin"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
 <item android:id="@+id/video_actiobar" 
    android:title="Video"
    android:orderInCategory="4"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

**the java code**

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: in which device you tested? with which android version? what happens on clicking menu button?

Comment: is this in fragment ???

Comment: menus on actionbar or actionbar on menu ;)

Comment: i never saw actionbar on menu ru sure?

Comment: @MichaelShrestha Android 2.3.3, Nexus S

Comment: then you need to use either AppCompat Library or ActionbarSherlock library to support actionbar..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, (Menu) menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the code to this way and check it works

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

check the link for more how it works (http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/)

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest, for your activity, make sure you declare it has Actionbar:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.test.activities.MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ActionBarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) or AppCompat for supporting actionbar for android versions below 3.0 .

For using ABS(actionbarsherlock)

You can extend your activity by `SherlockActivity`
and change your method to

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, (Menu) menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

as answered by @Amer Hadi

check here for more details [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Answer (score 0):

try 100% working on 2.2 to 4.4. just add support libraries.

```
 activity_main_actions.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >



 <!-- Refresh -->

     <item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:title="@string/action_refresh"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

<!-- Help -->

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_help"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
    android:title="@string/action_help"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<!-- Check updates -->

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_check_updates"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:title="@string/action_check_updates"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

code in activity:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
  {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }
```